# jQuery issues with kwicks accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider, kwicks

I'm working on a dev Wordpress site here: http://dev.completehcforwomen.com/ and for some reason I cannot get the Accordion on the home page to function. It appears to me that it is possibly related to a jQuery conflict as in the console I get this issue: Uncaught TypeError:

> jQuery(...).kwicks is not a function

for which I have found this in the page:

> jQuery('.kwicks').kwicks({
>               max : 930,
>               spacing : 0
>           });

I'm not a jQuery programmer but have been known to fix a couple things at random but this one is eluding me. Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be wrong here and what I should do to fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your webpage, It looks that you missed to include https://raw.github.com/jmar777/kwicks/v2.2.1/jquery.kwicks.min.js

Comment: Nimmi, thanks for the advise, though I gave it a try and it didn't do anything, this kwicks feature is built within the WP theme which is what is making this more difficult to exactly pinpoint what the issue is.

Comment: But in the source code of your given website I can not see that your kqicks.min.js is included. Please make sure.

Comment: Looking at your theme, this needs to be in your theme : http://coral.imaginemthemes.com/wp/wp-content/themes/coral/js/kwicks/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.pack.js

Comment: Nimmi, I checked again and turns out you were right, for some reason, upon updating the theme something broke with a particular theme include that contained the reference to the kwicks.min.js so it wasn't being included along with several other jquery scripts. Thank you for checking this, you helped me push on to figure what was wrong. Kudos!